# MVVM Activity Intent for Android

Tags: android, mvvm

I am trying out MVVM for Android.
I have a button which opens up another activity onClick.
Codes below:

View:

```
    <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/activity_test"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            tools:context=".mvvm.view.TestActivity">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Activity"
            android:onClick="@{viewModel.onClickButton1}"/>

    </LinearLayout>
```

ViewModel:

```
public View.OnClickListener onClickButton1() {
    return view -> {
        mContext.startActivity(new Intent(mContext, MockActivity.class));
    };
}
```

This doesn't seem to work for me. When I click on the button, MockActivity doesn't get started. What could be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

in your view file did u bind your view to your viewmodel?

binding.setViewModel(viewModel);

Comment: Accepted. 
I needed to setViewModel in my View Activity.
On top of that, I needed to add flag to my intent:
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

Answer (score 2):

As a suggestion, it is better to not include view event listeners in your ViewModel but instead putting them inside the View (activity or fragment here), Then you can call the view model methods to do the work. The idea is, ViewModel should not have any reference to view classes at all but in your code your passing a view to the `onClickButton1` method.

Answer (score 0):

Try viewModel::onClickButton1 instead of viewModel.onClickButton1

Comment: This won't make a difference.. It just gives a warning if you use '.' instead of '::'.. '.' is deprecated, but for now both are accepted.

Answer (score 0):

The code in your VM class should be

```
public void onMyButtonClicked(View view) {
    // YOUR CODE HERE
}
```

And in the xml:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:onClick="@{offlineDownloadsVM::onMyButtonClicked}"/>
```

Comment: Accepted. This is the correct code in the ViewModel